Visualforce page on SF mobile app is not working as expected
I have created a visual force page which updates bin locations based on Tag ID provided. Now my question is in web application I'm getting the blinker automatically on Tag_ID whereas in mobile application I have to constantly touch on Tag_ID to get the blinker. Our warehouse team who uses only SF Mobile app are complaining about this as they need to touch on Tag_ID every time to scan Tag_ID. Here is my VF page. Can anyone please help me on this. Thank you.
VF page:
<apex:page standardController="Bin__c" extensions="TagScannerController">

    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageMessages />               

        <apex:pageBlock title="Tag Scanner">

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Tag ID">

                <apex:inputText value="{!tagId}" label="Tag ID" onfocus="autofocus;" />

                <apex:commandButton value="Update Bin" action="{!scanTag}" />  

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock> 

      </apex:form>  

</apex:page>

We tried using different variables in VF page but was not able to get that pointer on the TAg ID on mobile app.
enter image description here
